# Вызов функции нажатем клавиши

Tags: python

Как вызывать функцию при нажатии клавиши клавиатуры? Типа :

```py
if (нажатая клавиша) == клавиша:
  print('нажатие')
```

Знаю, выглядит туповато, простите.
При клике на клавишу на выводе :

```
нажатие
```

Comment: Вместо создания дубликата, отредактируйте ваш предыдущий вопрос, добавив в него подробное объяснение, чего хотите добиться и с чем возникла проблема.

Comment: while sys.stdin.read(1): print('нажатие')